# Polyglossia's babelshorthands spoils write-to-file command behavior and conflicts with graphviz

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, write-file

Example (run `xelatex a.tex -shell-escape` twice, or just `xelatex a.tex` if you don't have `dot` installed and then explore generated files manually):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif} % Fonts are loaded to avoid compilation errors
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}  

\begin{document}
  \digraph{test1}{
    vertex[label="v1",pos="2,3!"];
  }
  \digraph{test2}{
    vertex[label="v2"
    ,pos="2,3!"];
  }
  \digraph{test3}{
    vertex[label=""]
  }
\end{document}
```

First and third graph are not rendered and corresponding `.dot` files are invalid, while the second one is ok. Spoiled files are

```
digraph test1 {
vertex[label="v1\penalty \@M \hskip .2em\ignorespaces pos="2,3!"];
}
```

and

```
digraph test3 {
vertex[label=\hskip \z@skip ]
}
```

Correct file:

```
digraph test2 {
vertex[label="v2"
,pos="2,3!"];
}
```

Looks like Polyglossia replaces some shorthands inside `\digraph` command's argument when it's trying to write to a file. Say, `""` with `\hskip \z@skip`. How do I disable that behavior temporarily, so no shorthands replacement is performed when executing `\digraph`? Probably, some character classes manipulation will be sufficient.

The `\digraph` command from Graphviz package [looks pretty straightforward](http://ctan.uni-altai.ru/macros/latex/contrib/graphviz/graphviz.pdf) but I do not have enough understanding of TeX internals and file handling to have a clue about what to do.

Comment: You can use `\shorthandoff{"}` before the graphs to deactivate the ", see the babel documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks! Did not thought about looking it up in Babel's documentation, Polyglossia's documentation does not mention `\shorthandoff`. Do you know any method to modify existing `\digraph` command so it will automatically disable/enable shorthands for its arguments? Naive `\renewcommand` does not work, probably because shorthands are processed before command execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\shorthandoff{"}` before `\digraph` (and `\shorthandon{"}` afterwards).

It's possible to patch `\digraph` so that it does the right thing; more precisely, one needs to patch `\@digraph` to insert `\shorthandoff{"}` after `\begingroup`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif} % Fonts are loaded to avoid compilation errors
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\def\temp\begingroup#1\@nil{%
  \endgroup\def\@digraph{\begingroup\shorthandoff{"}#1}%
}
\expandafter\temp\@digraph\@nil
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \digraph{test1}{
    vertex[label="v1",pos="2,3!"];
  }
  \digraph{test2}{
    vertex[label="v2"
    ,pos="2,3!"];
  }
  \digraph{test3}{
    vertex[label=""]
  }
\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of the three files after running the example:

```
digraph test1 {
vertex[label="v1",pos="2,3!"];
}
```

```
digraph test2 {
vertex[label="v2"
,pos="2,3!"];
}
```

```
digraph test3 {
vertex[label=""]
}
```

A strange way to patch the command, but it's quite resistent to other methods, because of the special tricks it does.